# How to keep Focus on JTextField while clicking input number buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am new to GUI stuff and am having trouble with the following problem. I have 3 JTextFields, credit card number, expiration date, and security number. I am able to input information into the fields. I also implemented the focus listener for each button. If I click it, it says gained focus, if I click anywhere else, it loses focus. Under these text fields, I have a number pad (touch screen/mouse click) to enter the numbers. How do I keep focus on that particular text field until ONLY and SPECIFICALLY one of the other two textfields are clicked? The textfield that currently has focus will lose focus once I try to click to input numbers. I don't want this to happen. I searched online and wasn't able to find something specific to my case. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Why is this happening?' - I provided you with working code. How is your code different? Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myJButton.setFocusable(false);
```

or if a bunch of buttons held in an `allMyButtons` collection:

```
for (JButton button: allMyButtons) {
    button.setFocusable(false);
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Ah. Now I can find lots of stuff online. I will try it out and get back to you later. Thank you.

Comment: Got it to work using this. Thank you. I set all my number buttons to false, and alternated the text fields between true and false based on what was being focused on.

Answer (score 3):

In additions to @Hovercrafts suggestion (+1) you will probably want to extend `TextAction` for the logic to insert the number into the text field. The `TextAction` gives you access to the last text field that had focus so the insertion code becomes very generic:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NumpadPanel extends JPanel
{
    public NumpadPanel()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(4);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(2);
        JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(2);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( textField1 );
        panel.add( textField2 );
        panel.add( textField3 );
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        Action numberAction = new TextAction("")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JTextComponent textComponent = getFocusedComponent();

                if (textComponent != null)
                    textComponent.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
            button.setFocusable( false );
            buttonPanel.add( button );
        }

        // Optionally auto tab when text field is full

        //SizeDocumentFilter sf = new SizeDocumentFilter();
        //sf.installFilter(textField1, textField2, textField3);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Numpad Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new NumpadPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using [Text Field Auto Tab](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/size-document-filter/) so focus moves from text field to text field as the text field becomes full.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I was not able to extend the TextAction class since I already extended a different class. There is too much code to deal with for me. But I ended up getting it to work with Hovercrafts answer.

Comment: @Harold, Yes, Hovercrafts answer addresses your question. The TextAction provides for better design. `I already extended a different class`, What different class? There is no reason you can create a simple class as I demonstrated. This class works independently of any class you may have already created.

Comment: I guess time was the reason. We were designing a POS system and I was responsible for sql/database stuff. The GUI team had too much work to deal with so I decided to try and help. I was lost and didnt know where to start. It was a good learning experience. Our project is complete, but I will try to modify the code to extend TextAction.